# I am getting Error 400 on sending the postRequest Function to Foursquare's API

Tags: json, swift, http-post, foursquare

The getRequest worked out perfectly and got the code 200 response and the json data. The postRequest function didn't work and returned Error 400. Any ideas on what could be wrong? Maybe my parameters are not stated correctly?!! Thanks

---

```
func getRequest(searchString : String) {

    let latitude = 44.3
    let longitude = 37.2

    let latLongUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&client_id=\(kFoursquareAppID)&client_secret=\(kFoursquareAppSecret)&v=20150111") //* find a way to pass the date format into the date area with the YYYYMMDD specific format

    let searchQueryUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=\(kFoursquareAppID)&client_secret=\(kFoursquareAppSecret)&v=20150111&ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)&query=\(searchString)")

    let searchQuery2 = NSURL(string: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi")

    //In the HTTP request, you need to pass in your client ID, client secret, a version parameter, and any other parameters that the endpoint requires:

    let task2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(latLongUrl!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        var stringData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(stringData)
        println(response)

    })

}
```

---

```
func postRequest(searchString : String) {

    let latitude = 44.3
    let longitude = 37.2

    let latLon = "\(latitude), \(longitude)"

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    //Setup the Params Dictionary
    var params = [
        "ll" : latLon,
        "client_id"  : kFoursquareAppID,
        "client_secret" : kFoursquareAppSecret,
        "categoryId" : "4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735",
        "v" : "20150111"]

    //Setup an Error
    var error: NSError?

    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &error)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //Call a completion Handler when this url call is complete
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, respose, err) -> Void in

        var stringData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        //Convert the String into a dictionary
        var conversionError: NSError?

        //This is the way we can convert the data into a dictionary into those keyValue Pairs
        var jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &conversionError) as NSDictionary

        println(jsonDictionary) //this will print out the value we are getting as a dictionary in the console.

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

---

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess that foursquare doesn't expect the parameters to be passed as JSON, but expects them to be passed as a part of the URL.

Comment: So essentially I'd have to pass the request as a URL then figure out how to break down the JSON data? Will give that a shot. Might be a solution.